# Mobile app on Deployd | Same origin Policy?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, same-origin-policy

I have a html5-JQM mobile app with a backend built using DEPLOYD. Since I am using JQuery Mobile for my mobile app (running from a file structure as of now) and also connecting to my cloud instance [here](http://xyz.deploydapp.com/) at the same time, this amounts to violation of same origin policy and hence CHROME stops it.

For testing purposes I am running chrome in a non-secure way. 
*Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security*

Now once I am done with I mobile app, I will use PhoneGap to generate the build. My target platform is Android. AFAIK, PhoneGap calls my web app inside a native webUI control.

Questions
- Does the same origin policy apply in the mobile scenario too? 
- I ask this because, Deployd currently doesnt support JSONP and if the answer to the aforementioned question is true then I will have to seriously rethink my backend.

Can you please guide me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand PhoneGap correctly, you should have no problems making cross-origin requests. In any case, newer versions of Deployd support CORS natively so JSONP (which is not a magic cross-domain bullet, since it only supports GET) isn't necessary.